# Single form in multiple pages using Flask and WTForms

Tags: python, flask

I have a form. I want to have the user answer the questions one by one. There may also be a progress bar at the top.

I am generating forms using WTForms.

What is the best way to do this?

Questions can also appear on the same page individually.